# Using Gstreamer, i can't ind a solution to send av1 video throught Udpsink in rtp packets

Tags: gstreamer, codec

I'm currently working on Gstreamer and my goal is to take video from camera(coded natively in h264) decode it, then encode in AV1 and send it in udp to another computer on the network.
My pipelines currently are :
Server :
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtspsrc location= rtsp://192.168.33.104:8554/vis.0 latency=1 is-live=TRUE ! decodebin ! autovideoconvert ! x265enc tune=zerolatency  bitrate=300 speed-preset=3 ! rtph265pay ! udpsink host=192.168.33.39 port=8123
Client :
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc address=192.168.33.39 port=8123 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H265,payload=96 ! rtph265depay ! avdec_h265 ! autovideosink
So with h265 it works but i cannot find how to do it with AV1 because i can't find a rtpav1pay (and depay).
Thanks in advance.

I tried to search for rtpav1pay but found nothing. I tried rtpgstpay(and depay) didn't work. The main goal is to use as little as possible the network without lag so maybe it's not the best solution. If you have any other idea please share it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are `rtpav1pay` and `rtpav1depay` plugins provided by [gst-plugins-rs](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/gst-plugins-rs); they can be built along with GStreamer if you enable the Rust plugins option, but you could also build them separately from their own repo (instructions on the README).